# How to check if all elements of a PageObject are valid (Java, Serenity, Cucumber)

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, serenity-bdd, page-factory

I am writing scenario test cases in cucumber and I want to check if all the elements of a PageObject are valid and selenium can interact with them, before I run the test. I want to avoid running my multi-step, long test case just to get to the last page and get an exception that an element is not found. I wanted to be able to test my PageObject after I write it, so I can be sure that all the elements are reachable (before running the long test..).

The website I am working on does not have consistent id tags and using @FindBy() sometimes takes some playing around with. I am trying to make a simple process of:

1. Navigate to the PageObject url
2. check if all elements in the PageObject are reachable by selenium

Do you know of a way to access all the PageObjects elements with out making a method for each one? A method that initializes all the elements?

Comment: A page object using page factory does not check for the existence of an element until you attempt to access the element.  This is by design.  The initElements method initializes all defined elements in the class to null.  If it instead attempted to access all defined elements, many classes would fail, as it is common to define all potential elements, even if they are not yet in the DOM but will be at a later time.  There is no shortcut here except to write wrapper handler methods to perform explicit waits and exception handling.

Comment: I don't know if this is lighter weight than just a method that initializes them, but you could bake a "self test" concept into your base page object, that allows you to register elements as you create them, perhaps with the element type (e.g. link, dropdown, input).  When you call `myPage.selfTest()`, it loops through all registered elements and exercises them according to their type (or just checks that they are displayed).

Comment: After a couple ways of trying, I can use reflection to get all the fields of the class and then check if each of them isPresent(). Because the the WebElementFacade variables are private, I have to place this method inside the class, which would mean I need to put this method in every class, and suggestions on getting around this?

Comment: Just as a side point, you might consider using `isDisplayed()`, since `isPresent()` only checks that the element is in the DOM (visible or not), and doesn't guarantee that the element is interactable.

Comment: @NathanielC, I agree, In my particular case, there are elements that are hidden in a modal or only shown after an event on the page, and in this case, the `.isDisplayed()` method would fail for those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a number of different ways, I used reflection within the class to pull all fields, and then used `.isPresent();` to check if the element is on the page. This solution requires this method to be placed in each class that you want to test, which I was trying to avoid.

Solution:

#### SuiteRunner

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features/checkElems")
public class RegressionTestSuite {}
```

#### Feature File: CanFindElems.feature

```
Feature: Check if WebPage Object elements can be found

  Scenario: Check if the page's elements are reachable
    Given navigate to webpage
    Then check page elements
```

#### Test Class

```
public class CanFindElemsTest {

  // Change the class
  ClassYouAreTesting page;

  @Given("^navigate to webpage$")
  public void navigate_to_webpage() throws Exception {

    page.open();
  }


  @Then("^check page elements$")
  public void check_page_elements() throws Exception {

    page.checkPageElementsExist();
  }
}
```

#### Page Class

```
public class SomeWebPage extends PageObject {

  @FindBy(id = "someID")
  private WebElementFacade someElement;

  @FindBy(linkText = "some text")
  private WebElementFacade someLink;

  @FindBy(className = "some-class")
  private WebElementFacade anotherElement;


  public void checkPageElementsExist() throws Exception {

    Field[] allFields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : allFields) {

      if (field.get(this) instanceof WebElementFacade) {

        WebElementFacade f = (WebElementFacade) field.get(this);

        if (!f.isPresent()) {

          System.out.println("ElementNotFound: " + field.getName());
        } else {

          System.out.println("Found: " + field.getName());
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: At the very least, you could move `checkPageElementsExist` to the base class, and make it take the array of elements as an argument.  You'd still have to wrap it in the child page objects, but it'd be a one-liner that calls the parent method and passes the elements in, instead of duplicating the whole method for every page object.  It feels like the kind of problem that has an even more clever solution though...

Comment: When I tried this. I could not access the variables, because they are private.